# can I get a function from an overloaded method in scala?

Tags: scala

Let's say that I have two methods defined with the same name and return, but different params:

```
def overload(x: Int) = x.toString
def overload(s: String) = s
```

Now I want to convert one of them to a function.  If the method weren't overloaded, I would do this:

```
val f = overload _
```

But since it is, the compiler rightly complains about an ambiguous reference.  Is there any way to make a function of one or the other of the overload methods other than to rename one of them?

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way the compiler knows which `overload` to call when you call it directly is by knowing the type of the argument it's applied to. `overload someInt` can only be referring to `overload(x: Int)`, so there's no ambiguity.

When you make a function from it, you haven't supplied an argument (yet), so the compiler has no idea what type you want your function to be, so it doesn't know which `overload` you're referring to.

The easy way to fix that is to explicitly tell it the type:

```
val f : Int => String = overload _
```

or:

```
val f = (x : Int => overload x)
```

or:

```
val f = overload (_ : Int)
```

(note: I haven't tested these yet, but some variation on them should work)

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I'll give them a spin.