# Scala delegate within multi-argument method call

Tags: scala, delegates

Assume there is a functional delegate method called "delegatedFoo()" that needs to be passed as an argument to a method (ie, scala's version of a function pointer) like so:

```
addMyDelegatedMethod(delegatedFoo)
```

Assume (for brevity), that line compiles/executes just fine. Now change it to this:

```
addMyDelegateOverrideMethod("uh-o", delegatedFoo)
```

This line will throw a compiler exception: **missing arguments for method delegatedFoo in class myClass**

Q: How does one go about passing a delegate (reference) within a multi-argument method call? (Is this something that can even be done in Scala?)

EDIT: to be more precise, the signatures would be as follows:

```
def delegatedFoo(str: String): String = { return "OK" }
def addMyDelegatedMethod(delegate: (String) => (String))
def addMyDelegateOverrideMethod(foo: String, delegate: (String) => (String))
```

**UPDATE**: after reviewing Paolo's answer and doing some more experimenting, as best as I can tell the issue (bug?) surfaces when there is an overloaded signature involved. (I didn't bother throwing that into my example above, as it wasn't used -- but just *having* it there appears to give my compiler a headache):

```
scala> object MyControl {
   def doDele(strA: String, strB: String, delegate: String => String) { delegate(strA) }
   def doDele(strA: String, count: Int, delegate: String => String) { delegate(strA) }
}
defined module MyControl

scala> def myFn(s: String): String = { println(s); s }
myFn: (s: String)String

scala> MyControl.doDele("hello", "bye", myFn)
<console>:10: error: missing arguments for method myFn;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
          MyControl.doDele("hello", "bye", myFn)
```

MyControl has a set of overloaded methods defined...comment out the overload method (or change its name) and the compiler will handle it fine... :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

As the error says you need to explicitly follow the `myFn` with a `_`

```
scala> MyControl.doDele("hello", "bye", myFn _)
hello
```

The reason for that is that in scala a method (what you define with `def` and lives in a class or object) is not a function (which is actually more like an object with an `apply` method of its own). In some cases you can pass a method where a function is required and scala will "transform" one into the other for you. In general, though, you have to follow a method with `_` to tell scala to treat it like a function.

Note this, for instance, in the REPL after your definitions:

```
scala> myFn
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method myFn;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied funct
ion
              myFn
              ^

scala> myFn _
res4: String => String = <function1>
```

__

Maybe you should provide a more complete example of what you're trying to do/what fails, but this works just fine in scala:

```
scala> def delegatedFoo(str: String): String = "OK"
delegatedFoo: (str: String)String

scala> def addMyDelegatedMethod(delegate: String => String) = delegate("meh")
addMyDelegatedMethod: (delegate: String => String)String

scala> def addMyDelegateOverrideMethod(foo: String, delegate: String => String)
= delegate(foo)
addMyDelegateOverrideMethod: (foo: String, delegate: String => String)String

scala> addMyDelegatedMethod(delegatedFoo)
res0: String = OK

scala> addMyDelegateOverrideMethod("hey",delegatedFoo)
res4: String = OK
```

Comment: Paolo - I think I need to do some more digging. I've tested the example out in the REPL and it works fine (after cutting out a bunch of dependency-related code), but it just will not compile in the SBT environment I'm working. So I'm going to experiment a little more to see if the error is incorrectly referring to a different problem - before I waste any else's time on it. Thanks for the input... -mjk

Comment: Paolo - It appears, as best as I can tell, to be a compiler "bug." I've updated the question will details on how to duplicate.

Comment: This is not a bug, but a (known) limitation when dealing with method overloads. Please see this other wuestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816547/can-i-get-a-function-from-an-overloaded-method-in-scala?rq=1

Comment: Can you explain? I read that one earlier but didn't see how it applied to this particular situation. Whereas that post is contending with the "inference" system of pattern-matching (to determine which is the correct overload to wrap), my method signatures should be differentiated easy enough - I can't see how the compile could possibly confuse a quoted String literal for an Int. In other words, even if you explicitly flagged the type of *overloaded* (i.e., second) argument, you still get the compiler error. Thanks.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella - thank you for the explanation. My understanding of what/how Scala uses "function pointers" was off just a bit. What really threw me was assuming that the compiler was breaking down the arguments list L->R, thinking it was hanging on the second argument (String vs. Int.) Thanks again...