# Scala - Passing function as parameter when function is overloaded

Tags: scala, function, playframework, overloading

I'm writing a function that looks like this:

```
def func(str: String, logFunction: String => Unit) = {
  logFunction(s"message is: $str")
}
```

When I try to pass Logger.info from Play framework, I get this error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (message: => String, error: => Throwable)Unit <and> (message: => String)Unit
[error]  required: String => Unit
```

It seems like it found the function with two parameters, and tried to pass that to my function. How do I specify the one-parameter Logger.info to be passed to my function?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, there are [two overloaded Logger.info methods in Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Logger).  To turn that method into a function and to choose the overload you want, you can explicitly specify the type and add an underscore after the function.  The underscore turns a method into a function, which is sometimes done automatically, but in the case can be done explicitly.  See also [how to get a function from an overloaded method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816547/can-i-get-a-function-from-an-overloaded-method-in-scala).

In this specific case try

```
val logger: String => Unit = Logger.info _
```